# Deploying a java webapp to tomcat7 in netbeans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, netbeans

I am running ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.I am developing a Java web app using Netbeans.I have configured tomcat7 in netbeans.However when i try to run the web app,i get this error

```
  http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext6600200080241952336.xml&path=/ussdHello
/home/mungaih/NetBeansProjects/ussdHello/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1050: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 37 seconds)
```

The line in build-impl.xml being pointed to is this

```
 <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="true" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
```

I have tried even changing debugmode to false but unsuccessfully.
The server log has this entries

```
  127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:50:33 +0300] "HEAD /netbeans-tomcat-status-test HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:50:33 +0300] "HEAD /netbeans-tomcat-status-test HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:50:33 +0300] "HEAD /netbeans-tomcat-status-test HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:50:45 +0300] "HEAD /netbeans-tomcat-status-test HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:50:45 +0300] "HEAD /netbeans-tomcat-status-test HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:50:45 +0300] "HEAD /netbeans-tomcat-status-test HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:50:45 +0300] "HEAD /netbeans-tomcat-status-test HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:50:46 +0300] "GET /manager/text/list HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:50:49 +0300] "GET /manager/text/list HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:50:52 +0300] "GET /manager/text/list HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:50:55 +0300] "GET /manager/text/list HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:50:58 +0300] "GET /manager/text/list HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:50:58 +0300] "GET /manager/text/list HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:51:01 +0300] "GET /manager/text/list HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:51:04 +0300] "GET /manager/text/list HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:51:07 +0300] "GET /manager/text/list HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:51:10 +0300] "GET /manager/text/list HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:51:10 +0300] "GET /manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext6600200080241952336.xml&path=/ussdHello$
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:51:13 +0300] "GET /manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext6600200080241952336.xml&path=/ussdHello$
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:51:16 +0300] "GET /manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext6600200080241952336.xml&path=/ussdHello$
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:51:19 +0300] "GET /manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext6600200080241952336.xml&path=/ussdHello$
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2013:16:51:22 +0300] "GET /manager/text/deploy?config=file%3A%2Ftmp%2Fcontext6600200080241952336.xml&path=/ussdHello$
```

Where might the error be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this will help very many people in future.
You have to install tomcat[v]-admin package in order to successfully deploy app from your netbeans installation.Reason behind that am not sure.So before running do

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7-admin
```

Replace the tomcat version with your version.
Happy coding.